# How do I redirect to my application profile page after I click on the application notification?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I have sent an application request to B using

```
 FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
        title: 'A request.',
        message: 'Rate Me! Request from: ' +thisname+' ',
        data: ''+thisimg+' '+thisurl+' ',
        filters: ['all'],
        });
```

When B clicks on the notification, he is taken to the application. I want him to be redirected to the application profile page. How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You put a javascript redirect in de canvas page, redirecting to the page : `<script>top.location.href = 'url to tab/page/anywhere';</script>`